# Cant pin wine apps in latte dock

Tags: wine

I cant pin wine apps in latte dock, Anyone knows how to get it to work? and don't ask me to switch to another dock just help me to get it fixed  :)
I'm in Kubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a `.desktop` file that describes your application in `~/.local/share/applications`

To do that:

`gedit ~/.local/share/applications/somewineappname.desktop`

and enter in

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=App Name
Comment=This is app
Exec=sh -c "cd /home/USER/.wine/drive_c/Program\ Files/APP_FOLDER; wine app.exe"
Icon=wine
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true
```

Replace `Name` with your applications's name, `Comment` with something describung your app `APP_FOLDER` with the Program Files folder of your application `app.exe` with the executable file name of your app

Drag and drop this file onto the dock and it should stay pinned

Comment: [Desktop Entry]
Name=Windows Live Messenger
Comment=Send and receive messages
Exec=sh -c "/home/sneakyboi/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Messenger; wine msnmsgr.exe"
Icon=wine
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Wine;
StartupNotify=true


is this correct? because the .desktop app is not opening :/

Comment: Can you run `sh -c "/home/sneakyboi/.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Windows Live/Messenger; wine msnmsgr.exe"` in a terminal window?

Comment: Nope, sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected

Comment: @Hemoo Ah yes! change the exec line to say: `sh -c "/home/sneakyboi/.wine/drive_c/Program Files \(x86\)/Windows Live/Messenger; wine msnmsgr.exe"`

Comment: ok lemme try that

Comment: still it wont work

Comment: @Hemoo does that command open the app in the terminal?

Comment: nope tried that it says "sh: 1: /home/sneakyboi/.wine/drive_c/Program: not found
wine: cannot find L"C:\\windows\\system32\\msnmsgr.exe" "

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80178/discussion-between-amith-kk-and-hemoo).

Comment: `Exec=sh -c " ......"` doesn't work after test, and I changed to `Exec=env WINEPREFIX="..."` and test, it's works!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt install wine
$ wget http://app.prntscr.com/build/setup-lightshot.exe
$ wine ./setup-lightshot.exe
```

Here's example, I tried to download and install **lightshot** through wine as above and then:

- Method 1: And then create an desktop file with no any *.ext and add an icon to specified path as below, it is works...
- Method 2: search the installed **lightshot** via Start menu, right click on the searched **lightshot** and add to desktop will do.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Lightshot
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/englianhu/.wine" wine-stable C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/englianhu/.wine/dosdevices/c:/ProgramData/Microsoft/Windows/Start\\ Menu/Programs/Lightshot/Lightshot.lnk -d
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
Path=/home/englianhu/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Skillbrains/lightshot
Icon=353A_Lightshot.0
StartupWMClass=lightshot.exe
```

The line `Exec=****** -d`, the use of `--password-store=basic` to avoid keyring message popup on auto-login, `-d` to run the startup application in background, `%u` is a url, `%U` are many urls, `%f` is a file while `%F` are many files.

and then refer to https://github.com/ibus/ibus/issues/2320#issuecomment-846158703 to set it as a startup application.